# STM32 - Pointers and sum

Tags: c, pointers, stm32, offset, cpu-registers

I'm learning how to program STM32 Nucleo F446RE board using registers.

To know the position of a register, I take from datasheets the boundary address and the offset.
However, I cannot calculate the sum of them. I show an exmaple:

```
volatile uint32_t *GPIOA = 0x0; // Initialization of the boundary adress
GPIOA = (uint32_t*)0x40020000; // Boundary adress from datasheet

volatile uint32_t *GPIOA_ODR = 0x0; // Initialization of GPIOA_ODR register
GPIOA_ODR = GPIOA +  (uint32_t*)0x14; // Calculation of GPIOA_ODR as the sum of the boundary adress and the offset (i.e. 0x14.
```

Line 5 gives me an error, do you know how to calculate it correctly?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your cast is wrong!. The right cast could be written as `GPIOA_ODR = (uint32_t*)(GPIOA +  0x14);`

Comment: the way is wrong. IMO it is too early for you for you. Yuo need to learn pointers and pointer arithmetic first. Use definitions from stm headers. They are correctly defined.

Comment: @lheb Albouda  it doesn't work. This was one solution I tried but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong. If you want to use this extremely inconvenient way:

```
#define GPIOA 0x4002000
#define ODR_OFFSET 0x14

#define GPIO_ODR (*(volatile uint32_t *)(GPIOA + ODR_OFFSET))
```

why `#define` not the pointer? It is just more compiler friendly and saves one memory read.

https://godbolt.org/z/LdLLVN

```
#define GPIOA 0x4002000
#define ODR_OFFSET 0x14

#define GPIO_ODR (*(volatile uint32_t *)(GPIOA + ODR_OFFSET))

volatile uint32_t *pGPIO_ODR = (volatile uint32_t *)(GPIOA + ODR_OFFSET);

void foo(uint32_t x)
{
    GPIO_ODR = x;
}

void bar(uint32_t x)
{
    *pGPIO_ODR = x;
}
```

and resulting code

```
foo:
        ldr     r3, .L3
        str     r0, [r3, #20]
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   67117056
bar:
        ldr     r3, .L6
        ldr     r3, [r3]
        str     r0, [r3]
        bx      lr
.L6:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
pGPIO_ODR:
        .word   67117076
```

Answer (score -1):

The cast should be outside the constant value, in other words, you are adding GPIOA address + 14 to generate a new address. So the cast must be outside them:

```c
GPIOA_ODR = (uint32_t*)(GPIOA +  0x14);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried but nothing. If I insert  the `GPIOA_ODR = (uint32_t*)(0x40020000 + 0x14);` it works, instead if I insert `GPIOA_ODR = (uint32_t*)(GPIOA + 0x14);` it doesn't work.
Some other ideas?

Thank you very much for the answer. The complete code I'm using is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /** RCC **/
    /* RCC */
    volatile uint32_t *RCC = 0x0;
    RCC = (uint32_t*)0x40023800;
    /* RCC_AHB1ENR */
    volatile uint32_t *RCC_AHB1ENR = 0x0;
    RCC_AHB1ENR = (uint32_t*)(0x40023800 + 0x30);
    *RCC_AHB1ENR |= 0x1;

    /** GPIOA **/
    /* GPIOA */
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOA = 0x0;
    GPIOA = (uint32_t*)0x40020000;
    /* GPIOA_MODER */
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOA_MODER = 0x0;
    GPIOA_MODER = (uint32_t*)(0x40020000 + 0x00);
    *GPIOA_MODER |= 1 << 16;
    *GPIOA_MODER &= ~(0 << 17);
    /* GPIOA_ODR */
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOA_ODR = 0x0;
    GPIOA_ODR = (uint32_t*)(GPIOA + 0x14);
    *GPIOA_ODR |= 1 << 8;
}
```

This code doens't work correctly because of the line `GPIOA_ODR = (uint32_t*)(GPIOA + 0x14);`. If I insert `GPIOA_ODR = (uint32_t*)(0x40020000 + 0x14)` it works correctly.

Comment: i'd suggest to define each register. `#define  GPIOA 0x40020000` you can write this before your main. That makes your code more readable and help you avoid such errors.

Comment: you need to learn pointers. Your code does not work as you do not add 0x14 bytes only 0x14 `uint32_t`s